# Ruby: How to execute part of codes from loaded file

Tags: ruby, json, file, load

I have very specific situation

I have separated file with json entries:

```
    {  
        "field": "value",  
        "field2": "#{Time.now + (24*60*60)).to_i.to_s}"  
    }
```

after I load this content using IO.read(file) I want to execute code inside with date defined in that value

how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other answer is faster

```
YAML.load(YAML.dump(hash))
```

---

I think what you are looking for is the [`Kernal#eval`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) method. This will run code which is contained within a string.

```
eval('2 + 2') # => 5
```

You may have to run a Regular expression first. See an example [here at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/ys05s1yIW0).

```
/#{([^}]*)}/
```

All said and done.

```
json["field2"].gsub!(/#\{([^}]*)\}/) { eval($1) }
```

---

If you want to do this for every single value in the hash.

```
json.each_value do |value|
  v.gsub!(/#\{([^}]*)\}/) { eval($1) }
end
```

---

References:

- [Ruby Docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval)
- [Mathematical Reference](http://msxnet.org/orwell/1984)

Answer (score 1):

I will do as below using [**`YAML`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html):

```
require 'yaml'
require 'time'
h = {  
        "field" => "value",  
        "field2" => "#{(Time.now + (24*60*60)).to_i.to_s}"  
    }  
p YAML.load(YAML.dump(h))
# => {"field"=>"value", "field2"=>"1377092990"
```

---

```
require 'yaml'
require 'time'
h = {  
        "field" => "value",  
        "field2" => "#{Time.now}"  
    }  
p YAML.load(YAML.dump(h))
# => {"field"=>"value", "field2"=>"2013-08-20 19:23:12 +0530"}
```

Comment: you know, everything is ok when I define string in code, but problem is when my string (json) is loaded from file